# Dynamically make width of a div as the first 3 columns of a table from a 4 column table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to be able to make myDiv have the same width as the first 3 columns from this table.

```
var tableColumnWidth = document.getElementById('artworks').rows[0].cells[0].offsetWidth;
console.log(tableColumnWidth);

document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width = tableColumnWidth * 3 + "px";
```

I have one issue left:

I am taking about the width of a column and multiplying it by 3, this won't work if the columns are not equal. so I need to dynamically take the width of the first 3 columns.

Here is myFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gmnhswdg/7/

Answer (score 1):

Usually *div*s will give you better results than tables. Just consider dividing all of this in two containers, one holding the first of the 4 columns and an empty space below and being 25% of the total width, and the latter (75% of the total width) holding 2 subcategories, an upper one with the 3 columns and a last one containing the text.
That's what I'd usually do but if you're limited by something or have some specific needs in coding this just tell me and I'll reconsider it.

Comment: Unfortunately I just have to update an older project and that part is made with a table, it will be so much to change if I give up the table.

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem anyway, the concept is the same you'd just need to change rows and cells. Maybe add a sub-table if needed but you could handle it easily without.

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
    var tableColumnWidth =0; 
            tableColumnWidth1 = jQuery('#artworks tr:first-child td:first-child').outerWidth();
            tableColumnWidth2 = jQuery('#artworks tr:first-child td:nth-child(2)').outerWidth();
            tableColumnWidth3 = jQuery('#artworks tr:first-child td:nth-child(3)').outerWidth();

            tableColumnWidth = tableColumnWidth1+tableColumnWidth2+tableColumnWidth3;
jQuery('#myDiv').outerWidth(tableColumnWidth + "px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code appears to be using plain JavaScript (the DOM API), rather than jQuery, although the code in your linked JS Fiddle demo wraps that code with jQuery's DOM-ready functionality. So, despite the presence of jQuery, I've opted to provide a plain JavaScript solution:

```
// using Array.from() to convert the enclosed expression into
// an Array, from an Array-like NodeList:
var threeCellWidth = Array.from( 

  // here we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve a
  // non-live NodeList of elements using a CSS Selector:
  document.querySelectorAll(

    // that selector finds the first three <td> elements,
    // using the :nth-child() pseudo-class, within the
    // first <tr> of the <table> element identified by
    // its id of 'artworks':
    '#artworks tr:first-child td:nth-child(-n + 3)'
  )

// here we iterate over the Array of <td> elements, using
// Array.prototype.reduce(), to reduce that Array down to
// a single value, or a single Array element:
).reduce(function(a,b){
  // a: the current value of the accumulator that
  //    Array.prototype.reduce() produces, after
  //    the previous iteration,
  // b: the current Array-element (<td>) of the Array
  //    of elements over which we're iterating.

  // here we add the offsetWidth of the current <td>
  // to the existing accumulated value:
  return a + b.offsetWidth;

// 0: the initial starting-value of the accumulator:
},0);

// here we retrieve the element to style, and set its
// CSS width property-value to the result of the
// retrieved value, concatenating that number with
// 'px' to provide a valid value:
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width = threeCellWidth + 'px';
```

```js
var threeCellWidth = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#artworks tr:first-child td:nth-child(-n + 3)')
).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.offsetWidth;
}, 0);
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width = threeCellWidth + 'px';
```

```css
#myDiv {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table id="artworks" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="myDiv">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi
  reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores
  placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis.
  Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora,
  facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id.
</div>
```

In the above snippet you'll note that the `<div>` is almost the right size, but still too wide. This is by design, and is the consequence of the width being calculated and then the `padding` being added to that width.

To correct the `<div>` to have the exact width of the first three columns of the `<table>`, we simply need to update the CSS for the `#myDiv` element, adding:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This causes the specified width of the `<div>` to include both the `padding` and the `border` widths:

```js
var threeCellWidth = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#artworks tr:first-child td:nth-child(-n + 3)')
).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.offsetWidth;
}, 0);
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width = threeCellWidth + 'px';
```

```css
#myDiv {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table id="artworks" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="myDiv">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi
  reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores
  placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis.
  Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora,
  facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id.
</div>
```

Incidentally, because `Array.from()` is an ES6 feature that may be unavailable to you, or your users, an ES5 approach would be exactly the same, but replacing the lines:

```
var threeCellWidth = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#artworks tr:first-child td:nth-child(-n + 3)')
).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.offsetWidth;
}, 0);
```

with:

```
var threeCellWidth = Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('#artworks tr:first-child td:nth-child(-n + 3)')
).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.offsetWidth;
}, 0);
```

```js
var threeCellWidth = Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('#artworks tr:first-child td:nth-child(-n + 3)')
).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.offsetWidth;
}, 0);
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width = threeCellWidth + 'px';
```

```css
#myDiv {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table id="artworks" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="myDiv">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi
  reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores
  placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis.
  Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora, facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt tempora,
  facere pariatur eligendi reiciendis consectetur repellendus sint maiores placeat odit nisi fugiat quo unde porro omnis. Eaque ea ad id.
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
  - [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Answer (score 0):

You already using jQuery so we can change the code to be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  resize();
  $(window).on('resize', function(){ resize(); });
});

function resize(){
  var tableColumnWidth = 0;
  $("#artworks tr:first td:lt(3)").each(function(){
    tableColumnWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
  });
  $("#myDiv").outerWidth(tableColumnWidth + "px");
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjfvea7d/6)

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. It doesn't take the width of the first 3 columns